# 'undefined offset errors' php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, zend-server

I'm trying to get a php program to build a multidimensional array from data in another array.

```
$n = 13;
while($n <=22){
    $itemName = $outputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_002']['value'];
    $itemUM = $inputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_029']['value'];
    $itemUnits = $inputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_032']['value'];
    $itemUnitsPrice = $outputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_045']['value'];
    $itemExtendedPrice = $outputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_060']['value'];
    $itemLT = $outputFields['FLD_'+ $n +'_076']['value'];
    $arrItems[$itemName][$itemUM][$itemUnits][$itemUnitsPrice][$itemExtendedPrice][$itemLT] = true;
    $n++;   
}
```

The idea end result should be like so:

```
Array
(
    [13] => Array
        (
            [itemName]
            [itemUM]
            [itemUnits]
            ...
        )
    ...
    [22] => Array
        (
            [itemName]
            [itemUM]
            [itemUnits]
            ...
        )
)
```

Currently getting "undefined offset" errors.

Comment: undefined offset error happens when you try to access an element in array which key does not exit. you can use `isset($arr['key'])` to check if key exist .or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$n = 13;
while($n <=22){
    $arrItems[$n]['itemName'] = $outputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_002']['value'];
    $arrItems[$n]['itemUM'] = $inputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_029']['value'];
    $arrItems[$n]['itemUnits'] = $inputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_032']['value'];
    $arrItems[$n]['itemUnitsPrice'] = $outputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_045']['value'];
    $arrItems[$n]['itemExtendedPrice'] = $outputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_060']['value'];
    $arrItems[$n]['itemLT'] = $outputFields['FLD_'. $n .'_076']['value'];
    $n++;   
}
```

Comment: when I do print_r, the structure is printed out perfectly, but fields are empty. still getting undefined offset error. tested out that variables had content through echo $inputFields['FLD_13_029']['value'], content is there.

Comment: Missed... Use dot - `.` to concatenate your strings. Edited my answer.